# Best DB architecture to maintain/update counters in near real time

Tags: database, counter, real-time, key-value

I am at the beginning of a project where we will need to manage a near real-time flow of messages containing some ids (e.g. sender's id, receiver's id, etc.). We expect a throughput of about 100 messages per second.

What we will need to do is to keep track of the number of times these ids appeared in a specific time frame (e.g. last hour or last day) and store these values somewhere. 
We will use the values to perform some real time analysis (i.e. apply a predictive model) and update them when needed while parsing the messages.

Considering the high throughput and the need to be in real time what DB solution would be the better choice?

I was thinking about a key-value in memory DB that will persist data on disk periodically (like Redis).

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The best choice depends on many factors we don’t know, like what tech stack is your team already using, how open are they to learning new things, how much operational burden are you willing to take on, etc.

That being said, I would build a counter on top of DynamoDB. Since DynamoDB is fully managed, you have no operational burden (no database server upgrades, etc.). It can handle very high throughput, and it has single-digit millisecond latency for writes and reads to a single row. AWS even has documentation describing [how to use DynamoDB as a counter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters).

I’m not as familiar with other cloud platforms, but you can probably find something in Azure or GCP that offers similar functionality.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Regarding the tech stack we will probably have issues with newest or not production-ready technologies as the target environment will be constrained by various policies. 

As a matter of fact we won't be able to use a cloud infrastructure.

Comment: Okay. DynamoDB is very stable, has been in production for many years, and reliably serves customers at a massive scale. However, it seems that not being in the cloud is the deciding factor here.